# Pandas: Merging rows into one

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have the following table:

| Name | Age | Data_1 | Data_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Tom | 10 | Test |  |
| Tom | 10 |  | Foo |
| Anne | 20 |  | Bar |

How I can merge this rows to get this output:

| Name | Age | Data_1 | Data_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Tom | 10 | Test | Foo |
| Anne | 20 |  | Bar |

I tried this code (and some other related (agg, groupby other fields, et cetera)):

```
import pandas as pd
data = [['tom', 10, 'Test', ''], ['tom', 10, 1, 'Foo'], ['Anne', 20, '', 'Bar']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Name', 'Age', 'Data_1', 'Data_2'])
df = df.groupby("Name").sum()

print(df)
```

But I only get something like this:

|  | c2 |
| --- | --- |
| Name |  |
| -------- | -------------- |
| Anne | Foo |
| Tom | Bar |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a groupby and a sum will do.

```
df.groupby(['Name','Age']).sum().reset_index()

   Name  Age Data_1 Data_2
0  Anne   20           Bar
1   tom   10   Test    Foo
```

Comment: Both answers satisfy my doubt, but this will be marked as the accepted for general purposes of my script.

Answer (score 2):

Use this if the empty cells are NaN :

```
(df.set_index(['Name', 'Age'])
   .stack()
   .groupby(level=[0, 1, 2])
   .apply(''.join)
   .unstack()
   .reset_index()
)
```

Otherwise, add this line `df.replace('', np.nan, inplace=True)` before the code above.

###### # Output

```
   Name  Age Data_1 Data_2
0  Anne   20    NaN    Bar
1   Tom   10   Test    Foo
```